# Connection Timed out - Apache2/Ubuntu server. Why?

Tags: connection, timeout, apache-2.2

I've managed to create SVN server that works on localhost (I used [this tutorial](http://alephzarro.com/blog/2007/01/07/installation-of-subversion-on-ubuntu-with-apache-ssl-and-basicauth/)).

Checkout and all other commands work locally (when I use the adress *https://localhost/svn/repository-name*)

I own a domain which points at my IP adress.

```
ping mydomain.com
```

returns my IP adress.

That IP adress leads to a router, which is configured to forward ports 80 and 443 to my server machine.

Unfortunatelly checkout https://mydomain.com/svn/repository-name is not working (Connection Timed out).

Why? Please help.

My server machine is running Apache2 @ Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that your router forwards connections made on the internal interface back into the internal network? It is very common that cheap routers only do the port forwarding on traffic that comes in on the external interface.

Try testing from outside your network and see if it works better.

Comment: +1 - this is a good possibility, do try it.

Comment: @pehrs how can I check this? My Router is D-Link DIR-100

Comment: Test it from the internet, perhaps via VNC or rdesktop to your home? Or use some website like this one: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Comment: @Eduardo this website sais that my 80 and 443 ports are closed.. i guess thats the problem.. how do i open them?

Comment: Double check your router config. This site may come handy: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Dlink/DIR-100/Echolink.htm

Comment: @Eduardo I re-entered & enabled following: 
**Name**: http **IP Adress**: 192.168.0.109 **Public Port**: 80 ~ 80 **Private Port**: 80 ~ 80 **Traffic type**: Any            
**Name**: ssl **IP Adress**: 192.168.0.109 **Public Port**: 443 ~ 443 **Private Port**: 443 ~ 443 **Traffic type**: Any 

             _checked again after router restart and the website still sais my ports are closed_

Comment: @Eduardo I also tried to set DMZ (Demilitarized Zone) to my server - it still didn't work :(

Comment: I can't be of more help with this particular issue as I don't own a similar router, sorry.

Comment: @Eduardo thank you anyways! you've helped alot..  I'll continue to investigate why my ports are closed, @pehrs also thanks to pehrs, I wish I could give you both +1 (unfortunately I can't yet - i need to be 15 rep myself to give arrow up)

Comment: @Piotr No problem. Stick around and answer a few question and you soon have your 15 reputation ;)

Comment: @Eduardo pehrs finally could give ya both thumbs up:)

Answer (score 2):

You either have problems with the port forwarding (that is: the packets arriving at your router are not reaching your server) or 443 is closed in the interface you're forwarding the packets to.

Try https://ip.being.forwarded.to/svn/repository-name locally (that is, in the server) with the IP you configured on your router. Does it work that way?

Also check for INPUT filtering (`iptables -nvL INPUT`). And post `netstat -ntlp` if possible.

Comment: https:// 192.168.0.109/svn/testPage/

returns my repository (just like https:// localhost/svn/testPage/)

Comment: _netstat -ntlp_ returns

`Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6601/apache2    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1113/cupsd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6601/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1113/cupsd      `

Comment: Can you test the same from some other server in the LAN? You can access it via a browser if you haven't got a SVN client handy. If it works then you know the issue is with the router/port forwarding.

Comment: _iptables -nvL INPUT_ returns `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 30 packets, 4974 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         `

Comment: I've tested it from another machine (plugged into the same router/in the same Local Area Network) and it works

Answer (score 2):

The problem was closed ports.

Port forwarding options did not work on my router. I had to reset it to factory settings and set it up again. Now it works fine.

Why did my router fail to forward ports? No idea. But resetting router fixed the problem.

**I'd like to thank @Eduardo and @pehrs for help!!**